# AngularJS does not evaluate expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am beginner in AngularJS, so I try to run basic code. However, this simple code does not work in a way I want. The html code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app> 
<head>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script> 
    function MyFirstCtrl($scope) { 
      var employees = ['Jon Doe', 'Abe Lincoln', 'Hugh Grant']; 
      $scope.ourEmployees = employees;
    } 
  </script>
</head> 
<body ng-controller='MyFirstCtrl'> 
  <h2>Number of Employees: {{ourEmployees.length}}</h2> 
</body>
</html>
```

I'd expect that the correct result is **Number of Employees: 3**
Instead of this, the browser (both Firefox and Edge) shows the following: **Number of Employees: {{ourEmployees.length}}**. Since other simple codes did work, the problem is surely not the reference to the *angular.min.js* file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please open the browser's JavaScript console and look for the error messages. They will tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global controller functions are no longer supported by default in 1.3. You should adopt `module` approach.

> $controller will no longer look for controllers on window. The old
>   behavior of looking on window for controllers was originally intended
>   for use in examples, demos, and toy apps. We found that allowing
>   global controller functions encouraged poor practices, so we resolved
>   to disable this behavior by default.

See example snippet :

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
       .controller('MyFirstCtrl', function ($scope) {

       })
```